# Oldish short story where a CEO's daughter gets an experimental treatment that's turning her into an alien

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this one or two (or more) decades ago, I think in *Omni* magazine.

It was told from the father's perspective; he's the CEO of a company that finds alien technology and is studying it.

His daughter for some reason (accident? sickness?) has to undergo an experimental treatment using their technology.  It seems to be a success, but she slowly turns into one of the aliens; the dad is desperately trying to find a way to stop/reverse it.

Comment: The girl was horribly burned, her father snuck home part of the alien's first aid kit which included this transplantable skin substitute that saved the girls life, when she began genetically transforming into one of these aliens which greatly disturbed her family IIRC), and built a ship to "go home"... with her chickens (which provided her what she needed for sustenance on the trip)… It was a short out of F&SF, and if I Can find it at home tonight I'll edit to post the name of it.